# Cannot change class objects within vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having difficulties with understanding how to change the value of a class object which is stored in a vector. From the example below, I thought the case would be that "ferrari" would be yellow after I change the color, however it is still black.

From what I understand this has to do with that I'm making a new copy of vector each time and therefore not changing the object I want. I have read that it might help to write the vector like a reference instead like so: `vector<Car> &cars;`, but this gives an error "reference variable 'cars' requires an initializer" which I don't understand how to solve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    string brand;
    string color;
    Car(string brand, string color)
        : brand(brand), color(color)
    {
    }
    // setter
    void setColor(string newColor)
    {
        color = newColor;
    }
};


int main()
{
    vector<Car> cars;
    cars.push_back(Car("bmw", "blue"));
    cars.push_back(Car("tesla", "red"));
    cars.push_back(Car("ferrari", "black"));

    for (Car car : cars)
    {
        if (car.brand == "ferrari")
        {
            car.setColor("yellow");
        }
    }

    for (Car car : cars)
    {
        cout << car.brand << " " << car.color << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should have `for (Car& car : cars)` in the 1st loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `for (Car car : cars)`, `car` is a copy of the corresponding vector element. Changing the copy doesn't affect the original.

Use `for (Car &car : cars)` if you want to modify the elements. Even if you only want to read (print) them, use `for (const Car &car : cars)` to avoid the unnecessary copy that you're currently making.

---

Also note that your constructor and setter are suboptimal. They need some `std::move`s:

```
class Car
{
public:
    string brand;
    string color;
    Car(string brand, string color)
        : brand(std::move(brand)), color(std::move(color))
    {
    }
    // setter
    void setColor(string newColor)
    {
        color = std::move(newColor);
    }
};
```

Comment: No need to make things more complex by using std::move if the parameter types are `string const&`. The end result is almost identical but the code is more idiomatic.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb That would stop the string from being moved (if it's an rvalue). I don't consider that idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

In your `for` loop:

```
for (Car car : cars)
```

So when it loops, it will make a copy of the `cars` elements, not the element itself.

Change that to

```
for (Car &car : cars)
```